# several virtual profiles for the same user

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables, profile

Many times there are several "identities" which one user uses: for work, open-source, academia etc., all require different ssh keys, editor configurations, git configs etc.

I was wondering if there is any tool for switching between such "virtual profiles" with the same unix user. Preferably it will enable you to also have different default binaries/libraries (for example, in one profile "python" will run python2.7 while in other it will be python3).

I know there is an option to set it up using a combination of environment variables, aliases and linked files but I was wondering if there is a more clean option like [virtualenv](http://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/virtualenv.html) in python provides.

Comment: Why don't you want to set up each identity as a separate user? That seems like the most straight-forward approach.

Comment: I think that a different user is pretty "heavyweight" for this. I also like to have the same graphical interface for all (and not having one user use another user window manager), so it seems right for me. In addition, I want some things to be shared, both in configs and in running applications (one browser, for example). So in short, feels heavier than I want, but this is what I do now.

Comment: Most of these seem tied to resources used by a different "identity" rather than the identify itself. `ssh` lets you choose keys based on the host you connect to and which user you connect as; editor settings seem more specific to what file is being edited rather than who edits it, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably use git branches for this. Set your home dir up in a branch and then create another branch and configure this how you'd like for this other "profile". It would be a matter of switching branch and then you'd have effectively a different looking home dir. Then you'd probably need to source your environment or run another login shell.

I haven't tried this myself but I think it should work.

Comment: i think it could work. i you use symbolic links to most of your config files into some git repository, you don't need to put the whole home directory in source control. I just wished there was a tool that made this easier (switching branches and sourcing the environment).

Answer (score 1):

iTerm 2's shell integration lets you define rules for profiles and automatically switch between them given the result of the rules. https://iterm2.com/shell_integration.html

Comment: IIUC, iTerm profiles are just for color schemes etc., not for switching binaries and other behavior

Comment: You can set the start commands and login shells for each profile. http://iterm2.com/img/screenshots/v2-screen-shots/profiles_general.png

Comment: Dedicated page for this feature: https://iterm2.com/dynamic-profiles.html

Comment: Now I get it - it is indeed useful, but sadly I'm not on Mac :)

Comment: Ah yeah. Good point. I wonder if tmux can solve this?